# How to render a collection of heterogeneous objects

Tags: angularjs

Given the JSON response:

```
[
  { type: 'A', name: 'Clem', created_at: '...', ... },
  { type: 'B', url: 'http://go.gl/H65Fs90x', created_at: '...', ... },
  { type: 'C', city: 'Berlin', created_at: '...', ... }
]
```

The hash has been simplified; consider it to be more complex than this example.

How can I render this collection of heterogeneous object with ngRepeat?

```
     <li ng-repeat="object in objects">
        // if object is of type A then render fields of object
        // if object is of type B then render fields of object
     </li>
```

Is this there a better approach? Something more "Angular-ish"?

Comment: Without comment on the method, using a 'data-ng-if' or 'data-ng-switch' with "object.type == 'A'' is a solution

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than two conditions or if structure is more complex then something like this (code not tested)

```
<li ng-repeat="object in objects">
   <span ng-if="object.type == 'A'">{{object.name}}</span>
   <span ng-if="object.type == 'B'">{{object.url}}</span>
   <span ng-if="object.type == 'C'">{{object.city}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) seems more suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to make the items you're binding to be responsible for knowing how they're to be rendered. This can be as simple as giving each item a templateUrl. Here is an example of this technique in action: http://jsbin.com/EhAnIMaJ/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: is it possible to move the rendering code `$templateCache.put(...'<div><input ng-model="filter...div>');` off the controller?

Comment: The example is only doing that so it works in Jsbin. In a real application you would have separate .html files (and use whatever mechanism for delivering your .html files that you use for the rest of the app).